# Solving the Differential equation x″=−kx+c

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Usually the best method for solving the ODE for the Differential equation of an SHM would be to take the trial solution $e^{mt}$ and hence solving the auxiliary equation. But clearly the 'c' term will pose a problem for these kinds of equations. So how do I solve them?

Comment: The $c$ poses no problem... it can simply be subtracted from the solution to the homogeneous equation.

Comment: Ohhhh yes of course! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x''+kx=c$$
Just rewrite the DE as:
$$\left(x- \dfrac c k\right)''+k\left(x-\dfrac ck\right)=0$$
$$y''+ky=0$$
Where $y=x-\dfrac  ck$
For $k=0$ just integrate the DE.